# How do I access the Activerecord setter I overrode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to use a custom setter to do some formatting of my fields.  In irb if I test the setter like:

```
o.field_name = "4"
```

I see that my custom setter is being referred to. But with this it is not:

```
o[:field_name] = "4"
```

I understand that in the first case this is a function call and in the second case we are just setting the attribute directly.  But I don't completely see how the attribute can be set without going through our custom setter, I thought that was the point.

But my main question is that if var holds my field_name, I don't see how to dynamically refer to a.var and have it be interpreted as a.field_name.  All I see to do is a[var] and this bypasses my setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `a.send(var)` where `var = 'field_name'`

That's the equivalent of `a.field_name`

Comment: ahh, so that what the question was asking ? :O +1 send is versatile indeed. Also take a look at eval for dynamic evaluation.

Comment: Ah I needed to check out the !ruby object page, lots of functions there that I was missing.  But the usage seems to be: a.send var.to_sym val which is giving me a runtime error while a.send(var.to_sym) = val gives me a syntax error.  I dunno, I'm about to give up on this idea of setters acting as formatters.

Comment: That shouldn't be giving you an error.. val is nil or something. Btw, you don't need to call to_sym, send can handle plain strings.

Answer (score 0):

o[:field_name] is like read_attribute(:field_name), thus is just reads the value as you said. It can be quite important in virtual attributes in order to bypass the stack too deep error. If you do a[:var], you just get its value. A virtual attribute refers to an attribute, if you are setting its value to another variable, you just get its value, not the object.

Comment: I'm confused as I am able to set the value by using a[var] = "val" where var = field_name, it just bypasses the setter.  There must be a way for me to not bypass the setter?

Comment: a.fieldname = "val" should not bypass the setter.

Comment: But the whole point of my question is that fieldname is actually a variable that holds say first_name, and so a.fieldname doesn't translate into a.first_name

Comment: I probably don't understand what you are asking. Can you please provide an example with values and actual field names ?